# Unable to get MonoDroidStartInfo for project

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I created a cross platform project (Xamarin App) in Visual Studio 2017. I didn't add any code of my own. I just built and ran it. It works for the android and iOS. However, for the UWP (Universal Windows Platform) it gives me an error like "Unable to get MonoDroidStartInfo for project".

Comment: Could you please try to open and compile your project with VS 2015, in order to isolate the possible IDE issue? And could you provide `Xamarin.Forms` version?

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms version was 2.3.3, but I am afraid I cannot check out VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

I set the platform target to x86 and it worked.